# compare two pictures

Tags: android, database, android-camera

[image]

I have the `Android` code for storing pictures in database. How can I compare a stored picture with a picture that is taken?

Comment: I stored some pictures in database. When im taking pictures using camera, i want to compare my stored picture and taking picture, if it is same it will display toast message images are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be several right answers, depending on what you're looking for.

If you're talking about comparing a new photo made with the on-device camera, there's virtually no chance it will be a byte-for-byte match with any existing file.

If you want to detect an exact match from a source where a copy is likely, look at the file size and dimensions of the two images. If they are exactly the same, then you can look at the bytes.  To save time, store a digital signature (e.g., an MD5 or SHA1) hash of the contents in the database along with the image.

If you want to find whether the images are similar in appearance, then you'll have to find some way to characterize the image.  I'm no expert at this, but in my naive approach, I'd do something like divide the image into a fixed number of regions and measure the amount of red, green and blue in each region.  You could even do this recursively on ever-smaller regions as approximate matches are found.  Comparing whole images will be a lot easier than finding a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

u can read it bit by bit and compare between it :) if it is the same.
like u know every file build from 0 and 1 so u can open it like binary file and compare it.

another solution. u can read about image and properties that save inside the image file (like : size ,width,hight,type)...

i hope i help ;)